# replace action attribute value in form

Tags: jquery

I am trying to change/replaced the action attribute in a form but am having a problem with the selector. I want to change the action to ShoppingCart.asp?recal=Y

Here is the markup for the form.

```
<form onsubmit="if (typeof(Update_Hidden_State_Fields)=='function') Update_Hidden_State_Fields(); if (this.submitted) return false; else {this.submitted=true; return true;}" action="ShoppingCart.asp" name="form" method="POST">
```

Here is the Jquery I have so far.

```
$("[name='form']")
.attr('action', function(jj,ww){
     return ww.replace('ShoppingCart.asp','ShoppingCart.asp?recal=Y');})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("[name=form]").attr("action", "ShoppingCart.asp?recal=Y");
```

Comment: LOL sometimes you overlook the simply stuff, I need some sleep. thx

Comment: I just need to add a comma and put the value I wanna change the value xD

Answer (score 1):

Why not the easy way:

```
$("[name=form]").attr('action','ShoppingCart.asp?recal=Y');
```

?

Answer (score 1):

What you have works, give it a try here: http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/Pgt5D/

I think you're missing is the `document.ready` wrapper, like this:

```
$(function() {
  $("[name='form']").attr('action', function(jj,ww){
    return ww.replace('ShoppingCart.asp','ShoppingCart.asp?recal=Y');
  });
});
```

Without running it on `document.ready`, unless your script is running *after* that form element in the page, it just won't find any elements to run [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) on.  By wrapping it in `$(function() { });` or `$(document).ready(function() { });` you're telling it to wait until the DOM is ready, and the element will be there.  Also I suggest changing your selector to `$("form[name='form']")` (if there are other forms with names) to make it *much* more efficient.

Comment: Hey Nick the reason it didn't work is I put my code in the wrong place so of course it wouldn't work but that code that I have seems a little overkill when I can just use other more simpler suggestions, but I did change the selector to yours